# Python: Why am i getting a recursion error with @Property and getter and setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, python-decorators

```
class Alphabet2:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value 

    @property
    def value(self): 
        return self.value      
 
    @value.setter       
    def value(self, value):
        self.value = value
 
    @value.deleter     
    def value(self):
        del self.value   



T = Alphabet2("The Word")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "c:\Users\ in <module>
    T = Alphabet2("The Word")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ in __init__
    self.value = value
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ in value
    self.value = value
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ line 1902, in value
    self.value = value
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ line 1902, in value
    self.value = value
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Hello, i know how to solve this problem and am familar with recursion but am looking for the logic and intuition behind this error and since involves recurrsion can someone explain which call or function is happening here, whats exactly happening. Whats throwing me off is that it is refering to an self.attribute but this isnt really a function call per say. Cant find docs about this on a more backend sorta level? any ideas?